# check when trying to assign Boolean

Tags: python

```
ctx['location_ids'] = vals['location_ids']
```

I have a large function so I will not post it here, but the problem is when `vals['location_ids']`  have values as integer everything works smooth, but sometimes there are no values in `vals['location_ids']` so it is `False`, and when it is `False` I get error.

```
ctx['location_ids'] = vals['location_ids']
TypeError: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

how can I avoid it, maybe add hasattr?

Comment: Check if it's `False` before using it...?

Comment: Yes, you can use `hasattr()`, but really you should probably do something else than assigning it a boolean value; keep things as uniform types (so if you expect to index `vals`, it should always be dictionary-like).

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds How would you use `hasattr` to check if a variable is `False`?

Comment: @Aran-Fey `hasattr(vals, '__getitem__')`...?

Comment: Ugh... Yeah, please don't do that. There's like half a dozen better ways to do it.

Comment: Yeah, not great. Wasn't suggesting they do that, just that they could. But not much worse than checking if something that should be a dictionary is a boolean IMO, and at least it follows duck-typing principles of Python...well, I suppose better would be `except KeyError` flow. Either way we can agree all of these solutions are bandaids, and the best action would be to change the code up the chain if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try to check first it's dictionary

```
if isinstance(vals, dict):
   ctx['location_ids'] = vals.get('location_ids', None)
```